# C# bind to comboBox without selectedItem and text population

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, selecteditem

My question is "Is there a way to bind data to a comboBox without the selectedItem and text values being changed / populated?" (I want the comboBox to stay blank)

This is an EXAMPLE of what I am doing:

```
        Dictionary<int,string> test = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        test.Add(1, "Company1");
        test.Add(2, "Company2");
        test.Add(3, "Company3");
        test.Add(4, "Company4");
        test.Add(5, "Company5");
        test.Add(6, "Company6");

        var list = test.Select(x => new { CompanyName = x.Value }).ToList();

        comboBox1.DataSource = list;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CompanyName";
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
```

If you run this code, it works fine, because it loads so fast, it looks like the comboBox stays blank.

However, if you step through the code, you will see that the SelectedItem and Text values get changed when the DataSource is assigned to "list".

My actual LINQ query is quite a bit bigger, and thus slower to load.  My comboBox "flashes" the Text value before it gets cleared out, and I want to remove this ugly flash.

I have tried different combinations of setting SelectedItem and Text values to null (or "") before and after the DataSource assignment, but I cannot get the "flash" to go away.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! =)

**EDIT:** I also want to add that this only happens on the initial form load... If I change the bindingsource and then reset back to my original (running the exact same code again), it doesn't "flash"...  Not sure if this helps or makes a difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple suggestion would be to just add the blank CompanyName as the first item in a list

```
list.Insert(0, "");
```

Comment: this is a little undesirable for me, since this leaves a blank item in my combobox... BUT, it's the only thing that's worked so far... so unless someone comes up with a better answer, I will have to stick with this... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `comboBox1.SuspendLayout()` and `comboBox1.ResumeLayout()` around your data binding code.  The first should prevent it from updating at all until the second is called.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but doesn't work for me... it could be that I have something else weird going on, but doesn't this have to do strictly with layout attributes?  
According to MSDN, `The SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout methods are used in tandem to suppress multiple Layout events while you adjust multiple attributes of the control.`

Comment: @JamesEkema - I'm pretty sure I've used it for this, but I didn't re-test it before answering.  I'm glad you found an answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

Add a null-Reference to your List as the first list-element before you set comboBox1.DataSource.

```
 var list = test.Select(x => new { CompanyName = x.Value }).ToList();
 list.Insert(0, null);
 comboBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, but I couldn't add an empty item so what I did was:

```
comboBox.ForeColor = comboBox.BackColor;
//set the combobox datasource
comboBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
```

That makes the combo box appear to be blank while setting the datasource without adding an empty item.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: removing the bindings, and then adding them back after setting the DataSource:

```
Binding[] bindings = new Binding[combo.DataBindings.Count];
combo.DataBindings.CopyTo(bindings, 0);
combo.DataBindings.Clear();
combo.DataSource = datasource;
combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
foreach (Binding b in bindings)
{
    combo.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue was adding a datasource in the form constructor and then in the form_Load change it to null, after that, when I set the datasource with my list, the text in the combobox keeps blank